# Why doesn't django.db.models.get_models() return any abstract models?

Tags: django, django-models

`django.db.models.get_apps()` returns a list of all installed modules containing models, regardless of whether they are concrete or abstract:

```
[<module 'apputils.models' from '/Users/Aaron/Sites/app/apputils/models.py'>,
 <module 'users.models' from '/Users/Aaron/Sites/app/users/models.py'>,
 <module 'profiles.models' from '/Users/Aaron/Sites/app/profiles/models.py'>]
```

But for some reason, `django.db.models.get_models()` only returns the concrete models, not the abstract ones (note the absence of any model from `apputils.models`):

```
[<class 'users.models.User'>,
 <class 'profiles.models.Profile'>,
 <class 'profiles.models.EditorProfile'>,
 <class 'profiles.models.AuthorProfile'>]
```

Is this a bug? If it's not a bug, is there some way that I can include my abstract models anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug. It's just not very useful for internal django use case to list abstract model explicitly.

One option is to convince django core devs to add this feature (because of the use case, you don't really stand much of a chance..)

Second option is to traverse models on your own like this (it gets models from app `myapp`):

```
import inspect
from django.db.models import Model, get_app

is_modelclass = lambda c: inspect.isclass(c) and issubclass(c, Model)
inspect.getmembers(get_app('myapp'), is_modelclass)
```

Comment: Then perhaps it's a bug that `get_apps()` returns apps that do not include any concrete models. At the very least, the documentation of both methods (as well as `get_app()` and `get_model()` needs to be updated. In the meantime, I have [opened a Django core ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21519#ticket) – no response yet, it should be interesting to see what they say.

Comment: Indeed, [my ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21519) was closed. "All these are private APIs; they aren't designed for general use and I have to admit that they aren't particularly well designed." Fair enough; I'll just need to stop relying on these API calls.